# I don´t understand this C program made with pointers

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, pointers

I saw this C program that copies the first string into the second one using pointers.

```
void copy(char const *s1, char *s2)
{ 
    for(;(*s2=*s1);++s1,++s2){};
}
```

I don´t understand the condition that stops the for loop, because I could have written `(*s2=*s1)!='\0'`and it works, but if I don´t write the !='\0' it works too. How does the for loop know when to stop?

Comment: The `for` loop stops when the condition expression is falsey or 0. `(*s2 = *s1)` has a value. If that value is 0, then it's considered false. If it's non-0, it's considered true.

Comment: "I understand why this works, but I can´t see how the for loop knows when to stop" -- that seems like a self-contradictory statement.

Comment: This function is designed to copy [zero-terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Null-terminated_string&oldid=933267984) (C-style) character strings.

Comment: @JohnColeman I think the OP means they know how it copies the characters, but don't know how it knows when it's reached the end of the string.

Comment: `while (*s2++ = *s1++) {;}` Kernighan-copy.

Comment: in a test condition `x` means `x != 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses are indicating that the test criteria is the result of the assignment to the location pointed to by `s1` (the left operand). In other words, the loop runs until the value of `*s2` is false.

`(*s2=*s1)!='\0'` is equivalent to `(*s2=*s1)!=0`, which is equivalent to `(*s2=*s1)`; or `(*s2=*s1)==true` if you prefer. Obviously a non-zero value is evaluated as true, so the loop runs until the second string has a nul terminator.

Comment: It's a programming style which semantically shows that a test is being performed. Like `if( ... )` or `while( ... )` etc

Comment: Those parentheses in an `if` or `while` are not style. They are required by the grammar.

Comment: "Like" as in "to make the reader think of", not "identical to".

Comment: The second part of the answer is Ok. However, The parentheses around `*s2=*s1` inside the `for()` actually do nothing, and not indicating a test criteria. While `if` and `while` require parenthesis as mentioned by @EricPostpischil, `?` expression does not require it and not normally used there.

Answer (score 2):

A character between single quotes is a char. The char `\0` has a value of `0` thus

```
char a = '\0`;
```

is equal to

```
char a = 0;
```

And thus `if (x != '\0')` is equal to `if (x != 0)`, which is equal to `if (x)` similar in the condition as part of `for`.

Comment: `'\0'` is an `int`

Comment: That is true, but the OP was using `char *`s.

Answer (score 1):

This gets at the heart of how C distinguishes between true and false.

*True* is any non-zero value (any bit on in an integer). While the condition tests like `==` and `>` produce a value of `1` any non-zero value works for true.

*False* is a value of zero (all bits off in an integer), which includes `NULL` in pointers.

The value of `'\0'` is of course a binary zero so the `(*s2++=*s1++)`  in the condition part of the `for` does an implicit test for non-zero so this works up, and until, the `\0` is copied. The `\0` returns false and exits the loop.  Adding your own `!='\0'` is adding an explicit test for the same.

*Beware:* If you just used an incorrect `*s1++ = *s2++ != '\0'` without the parenthesis it would be treated as a very buggy `*s1++ = (*s2++ != '\0')` which would assign a series of 1's to *s1 followed by a `'\0'` to terminate the "string". Oops.